# Moq: Verifying a method was called with a particular delegate produces "method argument length mismatch"

Tags: delegates, mono, moq

I've got a class `A` that calls a method on interface `B`, passing to it one of its own methods as sort of a continuation that `B` is supposed to call when it has a result. The code seems to work fine in practice, but I can't figure out how to test it with Moq -- when I try the obvious thing, it produces `System.ArgumentException : method argument length mismatch`. Thought at first it might be my code, but it fails the same way with the following toy case:

```
public class A
{
    readonly B myB;

    public A (B b)
    {
        myB = b;
    }

    public void HandleC (C c)
    {
        // do something
    }

    public void DoFindC ()
    {
        myB.FindC (HandleC);
    }
}

public interface B
{
    // Finds a C and then passes it to handleC
    void FindC (Action<C> handleC);
}

public interface C
{
}

[TestFixture()]
public class ATest
{
    [Test()]
    public void TestDoFindC ()
    {
        Mock<B> bMock = new Mock<B> ();
        A a = new A(bMock.Object);
        a.DoFindC();

        bMock.Verify(b => b.FindC(a.HandleC));
    }
}
```

I'm guessing there's some behind-the-scenes magic with delegates that I don't understand yet, being relatively new to C#, but what's the right way to test this?

---

**Update:** For reference, I'm using Mono 2.6.7 on MacOS 10.6.5 and targeting .NET 3.5.

---

**Updated again:** Best guess is that this is a Mono bug; I've filed it as https://bugzilla.novell.com/show_bug.cgi?id=656918.

Comment: I just copied your code and the test passed.  I'm using xUnit, but I don't think that would matter.  Are you using the latest version of Moq?

Comment: I'm using Moq 4.0.10827 -- seems to still be the latest version. Maybe it's a Mono bug? I'm using Mono 2.6.7 and targeting .NET 3.5, if that might make a difference. I don't see any NUnit classes in the stack trace, so it's probably not NUnit vs xUnit.

Comment: I just re-ran the test targeting .NET 3.5 and it passed.  At this point I'd say it looks like an issue with Mono.

Comment: Thanks @adrift. I've filed a bug: https://bugzilla.novell.com/show_bug.cgi?id=656918

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mono bug: https://bugzilla.novell.com/show_bug.cgi?id=656918.