# How can I get a reference to a method based on a string?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to get a reference to a method based on a string so I can pass it on to `UnityAction`.

```cs
public class FluentUtility
{
    //...

    public FluentUtility AddComponent<T>()
    {
        gameObject.AddComponent<T>();

        return this;
    }

    public FluentUtility AddButton(string methodName)
    {
        // Works but not general purpose
        var action = new UnityAction(component.exampleMethod);

        // Pseudocode of what I'm looking for
        var action = new UnityAction(component.GetInvokable(methodName));

        //...

        return this;
    }
}
```

I mostly come across examples for invoking a method based on a string, but that's not what I'm looking for. As `UnityAction` expects the argument to derive from `UnityEngine.Object` I can't use a lambda either.

Is this possible or am I missing something obvious? I'm just guessing my way around C#.

Comment: Why do you want to go through string at all?

Comment: @derHugo I already had some alternative idea as explained in my self-answer, but the string approach works too after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the method from the objects `Type`.
Then use an anonymous function in the `UnityAction` constructor to invoke the method.

```
var method = component.GetType().GetMethod(methodName);
var action = new UnityAction(() => method.Invoke(component, null));
```

In order to use `UnityEventTools.AddPersistentListener`, you need to get a valid method using `UnityEvent.GetValidMethodInfo` as show in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40655089/how-to-add-persistent-listener-to-button-onclick-event-in-unity-editor-script).

Below is a function for creating the `UnityAction` from a `UnityEngine.Object` given a method name.

```
private UnityAction CreateValidAction<T>(T obj, string methodName) where T : UnityEngine.Object
{
    var method = UnityEvent.GetValidMethodInfo(obj, methodName, new System.Type[] { });
    var action = (UnityAction)System.Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(UnityAction), obj, method, false);

    return action;
}
```

Here is a simple test of the function.

```
private void Start()
{
    TestEvent();
}
private void TestEvent()
{
    var action = CreateValidAction(this, "TestEventMethod");
    var mEvent = new UnityEvent();

    UnityEditor.Events.UnityEventTools.AddPersistentListener(mEvent, action);

    mEvent.Invoke();
}
private void TestEventMethod()
{
    Debug.Log($"Test Event Method Called!");
}
```

Comment: Well, as I said, this does unfortunately not seem to work for `UnityAction`, or at least not in relation with `UnityEventTools.AddPersistentListener`. I guess I should've mentioned that. 

Comment: No problem. Please incorporate `UnityEventTools.AddPersistentListener` in your question.   I tested my code above and it works.  But when using the forementioned function, the class is null during registration validation.  Im guessing its checking the method passed in exists on the class, which it doesnt since its anonymous (just a guess..).

Comment: Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40655089/how-to-add-persistent-listener-to-button-onclick-event-in-unity-editor-script), it looks promising.

Comment: Thanks! `UnityEvent.GetValidMethodInfo` does the trick. If you can post an answer I'll accept it later today, otherwise I post one.

Answer (score 0):

I clarified my example a bit and came up with an alternative. Instead of passing in the method name I pass in a delegate that is provided with the component so I can pick the method reference from outside.

```cs
public FluentUtility AddButton<T>(Func<T, UnityAction> getAction)
    where T : Component
{
    var action = getAction(gameObject.GetComponent<T>());

    //...
}
```

```cs
fluentObject
    .AddComponent<ExampleComponent>()
    .AddButton<ExampleComponent>(
        (component) => new UnityAction(component.exampleMethod)
    );
```

Unfortunately I can't figure out how to type this to put the `new UnityAction` inside `AddButton` and just return the method reference instead. I seem to run into the same "`null` does not derive from `UnityEngine.Object`" issues when I try.