# Delegate.CreateDelegate with lambda as method produces "method argument length mismatch" exception

Tags: c#, .net, lambda, delegates, mono

I have a problem, Test1 produces "System.ArgumentException : method argument length mismatch" while Test2 and Test3 passes fine. I need to subscribe to an event using reflection, everything works if I use simple methods, but when I get into lambdas, it stops working as expected.

Debugging shows for all lambdas that they are "Void <>m__0(Int32)" which is the correct type for event and the same as "eventInfo.EventHandlerType".

Why does it fail? Or maybe, how to workaround that?

Do c# add more arguments to a method which is created by lambda like in Test1?

::Complete code here:

```
public class A
{
    public void Test1()
    {
        var str = "aa";
        B.Subscribe(typeof(C), "myEvent", (int a) => { var any = str; }, null);
    }

    public void Test2()
    {
        B.Subscribe(typeof(C), "myEvent", (int a) => { var any = a; }, null);
    }

    public void Test3()
    {
        B.Subscribe<int>(typeof(C), "myEvent", callback, this);
    }

    public void callback(int a) { }
}

public static class B
{
    public static void Subscribe<T>(Type type, string eventName, Action<T> callback, object target)
    {
        var eventInfo = type.GetEvent(eventName, BindingFlags.GetField | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
        var handler = Delegate.CreateDelegate(eventInfo.EventHandlerType, target, callback.Method);
        eventInfo.AddEventHandler(null, handler); 
    }

}

public sealed class C
{
    public static event Action<int> myEvent;
}
```

EDIT:

Apparently it's Mono bug. GetInvocationList()[0] to get the Delegate fixes the issue in above example.

But subscribing to event produces "System.InvalidCastException : Cannot cast from source type to destination type." If event is not of type Action but of custom delegate: (if class "C" is like that, it throws, if class "C" is like above, it passes fine)

```
public sealed class C
{
    public static event MyDel myEvent;
    public delegate void MyDel(int a);
}
```

Is it different issue? Edit #2, event expects `MyDel` type, but gets Action Int32. How can I convert from `Action<T>` to MyDel or better, to `eventInfo.EventHandlerType`, because I don't know what type of event there can be.

Comment: Works fine with MS .NET. May be some Mono issues?

Comment: Seems to bug a mono bug. Check this http://lists.ximian.com/pipermail/mono-bugs/2010-December/106824.html

Comment: What happens if you use `GetInvocationList()` (i.e. first element of the returned list) instead of `Method`? The latter ought to work, but as @VinSmile says, maybe a Mono issue.

Comment: Assuming it's the same bug, possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4328075/moq-verifying-a-method-was-called-with-a-particular-delegate-produces-method-a. At the very least, related.

Comment: @PeterDuniho GetInvocationList()[0] fixes issue in above example, but fails in full project. Updated the question. Thanks so far, at least it's moving forward.

Comment: Cannot find any workaround. Delegate.CreateDelegate seems to be the only one which can create Delegate of fully dynamic and generic type.

Comment: Does Mono support `Expression`? That is one alternative way to dynamically create a delegate instance that I know of. Alternatively, in your scenario, do you really need fully dynamic code? You seem to be passing a specific delegate type already, and that delegate type seems to need to be compatible with the event type, so can't you just use that passed delegate instance directly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, after further investigation I noticed that my `target` was bad.

For methods defined in class, class instance as target is okay.
For lambdas I thought it was null, at least it works with null, **as long as it does not interfere with local variables defined inside the method where the lambda was created.**

So **Action** has a property **Target**, using `callback.Target` in `Delegate.CreateDelegate` solves the issue.

The target for lambda actually holds a reference to the class instance and to the all local variables it touches (debugger shows it).

Strange that it worked on newest .NET, maybe a slight difference between mono and .NET.